# Recover README.mD file lost by force push

Tags: git, github, git-push, readme

I was writing a README.md file in the remote server and completed that one, but I accidentally did a force push to the remote by using git push -f origin master and now the README.md file is gone.

Is there any way I can retrieve that commit?

Comment: Did you commit the README?

Comment: If you did it on the console, you should have the id of the commit that was _previously_ in the remote branch. You could use that commit id to get the file back (if you fetched).

Comment: I first committed the README file in github only. Then, i added a image in my project in vs code and pushed it using push -f origin master but as soon as I ran this command my README file changes were gone(it was back to its original state).

Answer (score 1):

Locally : try `git reflog origin/master` and see if your commit is there.

On GitHub : there is an [events API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/activity/events#list-repository-events), look for `PushEvent`s, and the `"before"` field.

Once you get the commits hash, you should be able to run `git fetch origin <sha>`, then `git checkout <sha>:README.md`.

Comment: Simple talk-thru: https://medium.com/git-tips/githubs-reflog-a9ff21ff765f